# JLabel does not show up

Tags: java, swing, label

I have been following the tutorial of a youtube video, but although my code is basically a carbon copy of this person's, my JLabel did not show:

Note: I will use a Layout later, I'd like to do this without first.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("blusq.png");
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Hi");
        label.setIcon(icon);
        
        
        JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
        redPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        redPanel.setBounds(0,0,250,250);
        
        JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        bluePanel.setBounds(250,0,250,250);
        
        JPanel greenPanel = new JPanel();
        greenPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        greenPanel.setBounds(0,250,500,250);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(750,750);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        bluePanel.add(label);
        frame.add(redPanel);
        frame.add(bluePanel);
        frame.add(greenPanel);
        
    }
}
```

I have been able to make the label show up by putting the "frame.setVisible" line to the end of code, but I'd like to know why this works for the youtube guy but not for me?

Also, I can't seem to add the label to both the frame and a label at the same time, which I don't quite understand either:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        bluePanel.add(label);
        // frame.add(label);
        frame.add(redPanel);
        frame.add(bluePanel);
        frame.add(greenPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(750,750);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Works

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        bluePanel.add(label);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(redPanel);
        frame.add(bluePanel);
        frame.add(greenPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(750,750);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Does not work

Comment: *"... I will answer my own question above: yes, a JLabel is by default visible, and so your suggestion, while well-meaning, is guaranteed not to solve the original poster's problem."* -- it works because it's a fluke on the You Tuber's operating system's Java Swing GUI rendering system. Their code is unsafe and buggy (as you're finding out), and the key take-away from this is to not trust anything that that you tuber is posting.

Comment: Thank you, got any recommendations for better content?

Comment: Yes, check out the check out the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) as well as links to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). And avoid using null layouts now and layout managers later.  Learn and use the layout managers now.

Comment: The assignment for which I am researching this does not allow for the use of layout managers, but as I can't figure it out otherwise, I might as well. Thank you kindly for the help!

Comment: Oh no, I should have known you were going to redirect me to the official documentation. I struggle with understanding the official javadoc

Comment: Truth: Keep struggling, since the more you struggle at it, the easier it will get

Answer (score -1):

You should add 'label.setVisible(true);' to your code.

Comment: Is the visible property of a JLabel set to true by default?

Comment: This does not seem to change the result sadly

Comment: I will answer my own rhetorical question above: yes, a JLabel is by default visible, and so your suggestion, while well-meaning, is guaranteed not to solve the original poster's problem.

Comment: @PeterPefi: that is because the suggestion given by RyanW is guaranteed to fail. Your problem is likely due to *where* you call `.setVisible(true)` on the JFrame, not the JLabel. Do it *after* all components are added, not before, otherwise, your JFrame will render *before* components have been added, and those components won't show.

Comment: Yes, that is how I get it to work but here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kmgo00avvEw at 36:12, the guy does not need to rearrange his code.

Comment: @PeterPefi: on *his* system, and his system only. Again, do not trust that YouTube account to teach good programming practices.

Comment: Got it, you got any good sources for this?